# Constraint layout always alinging to top left corner

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was trying to aling some EditTexts in three columns. But all I get is this. You can't even see them without selecting them in design editor. I tried adding them separately and setting the constraints as I go along and adding all of them and setting constraint after that. None of which helped. I'm lost, I thought constraint's layouts were supposed to be easy to create :/

everything merged with no width and no height

[image]

w/o select

[image]

Here's the constraint layout:

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/karta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hpTmp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Tmp HP"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/hpMax"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Class" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hpMax"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Max HP"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/hpNow"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/hpTmp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Race" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hpNow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Current HP"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/hpMax"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Level" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Class"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Klasa"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/Race"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Alignment" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Race"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Rasa"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Level"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/Class"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Proficiency" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Level"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Poziom"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/Race"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Background" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Alignment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Alignment"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Proficiency"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Proficiency"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Proficiency"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Background"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/Alignment"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Background"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="Background"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:tag="staty"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Proficiency"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you learn more about constraints, you are not using it quiet right

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
```

You see this line from your xml code, it will just put your view out of screen, instead it should be app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

Comment: I just used the LayoutEditor, didn't think it would be a problem :/

Comment: @BartoszZiembański I think you can handle things better if you write your own xml code instead of depending on the LayoutEditor

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` or  `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: wrap_content makes them visible but still is showing them weirdly, match_parent is not available for constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/karta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hpTmp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Tmp HP"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/hpMax"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Class" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hpMax"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Max HP"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/hpNow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/hpTmp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Race" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hpNow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Current HP"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/hpMax"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Level" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Class"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Klasa"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Race"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Alignment" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Race"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Rasa"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Level"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/Class"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Proficiency" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Level"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Poziom"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/Race"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Background" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Alignment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Alignment"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Proficiency"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Proficiency"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Proficiency"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/Background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/Alignment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Background"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:tag="staty"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Proficiency"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Result:

[image]

Think of constraints as A's given edge attached/aligned to B's given edge. So for example, `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` constraint means A's starting edge is attached/aligned to B's ending edge.

It's much better to write your code in your xml first before using the layout editor. This way, you'll know how it works.